# How to display negative value on comparing and matching the table rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am loading an Excel file into SQL Server and storing the data as per requirement as per the query shared by converting multiple rows in to single based on criteria.

I have the SQL query shown here, which is working as expected but instead of positive results, I would like to check if the prev/first row as per query has the `-` symbol and append it to the quantity.

Here is the sample query I am trying out and expected output explained in image

```
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE
(
    RowID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    InvoiceDate NVARCHAR(20),
    Description NVARCHAR(MAX),
    Quantity NVARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO @tmpTable
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
('07/18/2021','MedName','-18'),
(NULL,'18 Patient1',''),
('07/18/2021','MedName','-5'),
(NULL,'2 Patient2',''),
(NULL,'3 Patient3',''),
('07/18/2021','MedName','7'),
(NULL,'1 Patient2',''),
(NULL,'6 Patient3','')
) AS temp
(InvoiceDate,
    Description,
    Quantity)

    SELECT * FROM @tmpTable

DECLARE @tblTmp TABLE
    (
        RowID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
        InvoiceDate NVARCHAR(20),
        Description NVARCHAR(MAX),
        Quantity NVARCHAR(20)
    )
    DECLARE @tblTmp1 TABLE
    (
        [RowID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
        [InvoiceDate] DATETIME,
        [MedDescription] [NVARCHAR](MAX),
        [Quantity] [DECIMAL](18,2)
    )
    BEGIN TRY
    

    --SELECT * FROM @invoiceTable

    INSERT INTO @tblTmp
    SELECT InvoiceDate,   Description, Quantity FROM @tmpTable
    ; WITH
        CTE (InvoiceDate , Description,  Quantity) AS (
    SELECT t1.InvoiceDate,  t1.Description, t2.Quantity
    FROM (
       SELECT *
       , ISNULL((SELECT MIN(RowID) FROM @tblTmp st WHERE InvoiceDate is NOT NULL and st.RowId > t.RowId) -1, (SELECT MAX(RowID) FROM @tblTmp)) NewVal
       FROM @tblTmp t
       WHERE InvoiceDate is NOT NULL
       ) t1
       JOIN (
       SELECT RowID, LTRIM(RIGHT(Description, LEN(Description) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', Description ))) CustomerPo,
       CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(LEFT(Description, CHARINDEX(' ', Description) -1)) = 1 THEN
      LEFT( Description, CHARINDEX (' ', Description) -1) ELSE 0 END Quantity
       FROM @tblTmp
       WHERE InvoiceDate is NULL
       --AND Description <> 'NON RETURNABLE'
       ) t2 ON t2.RowId BETWEEN t1.RowID and t1.NewVal
       )


    --SELECT * FROM CTE;
    INSERT INTO @tblTmp1 (InvoiceDate , MedDescription,  Quantity)
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,InvoiceDate, 101)  , Description,
    Quantity
    
    FROM CTE;

    SELECT * FROM @tblTmp1
    
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
 SELECT
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
    ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
    ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
    ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
    ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
    ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH;
```

[image: No change as posiitve value]

Comment: Ok, so if it does have a negative value what do you want to happen..?

Comment: Also pet peeve: The semi colon (`;`) is a statement *terminator*; it goes at the end of **every**. It doesn't go at the *start* of statements that require the **previous** statement to be properly terminated.

Comment: It should show as per last 2 rows

Comment: As CTE required semicolon I added it, but yes it should be at the end

Comment: *What* should show as the last 2 rows? If we run your statements above it returns the values in your image. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9c76f22aeabf06b30686cbbbb4b04481)

Comment: It will show as 6 and 1 that's it. I would like to display - symbol before each row if the main quantity has negative value in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238439/discussion-between-developer-and-larnu).

Comment: Rather than asking me to chat, [edit] your question to make it clear so that others can understand as well. Perhaps explain the goal you are trying to achieve too, as the above may well be overly complicated. The fact that you are storing the quantity, which appears to be an integer value, as an `nvarchar` is likely the first flaw in the problem. That `InvoiceDate` is also an `nvarchar` (when it clearly should be a `date`) the second. Fix your data types first; then worry about doing arithmetic on said numeric values. Doing such tasks on string based "numbers" never works out well.

Comment: As said I am loading the data from excel and passing it to table type I kept all the fields as nvarchar

Comment: And, like I said, that's your first problem. If you have strongly typed data, your issue may well "disappear".

Comment: But still the issue will be there as I am copying the alternate row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is returning the wrong value. You wanted `sign(t1.Quantity) * t2.Quantity` rather than just `t2.Quantity`.

If you'd like an alternative that eliminates the subqueries you might consider approaching it with analytic functions. These would require a somewhat newer version of SQL Server in case that's a consideration.

```
with data as (
    -- use gaps and islands to gather rows into groups
    select *, count(InvoiceDate) over (order by RowId) as Grp
    from @tmpTable
), lookBack as (
    select
        -- grab the corresponding invoice date, medname, sign and row id
        RowId, min(RowId) over (partition by grp) as MinRowId,
        min(InvoiceDate) over (partition by grp) as InvoiceDate,
        first_value(Description) over (partition by grp order by RowId) as MedName,
        Description,
        sign(try_parse(min(Quantity) over (partition by grp) as int)) as Sgn
    from data
)
select InvoiceDate, MedName, Quantity
from lookBack cross apply (
    select Sgn * try_parse(value as int) as Quantity
    from string_split(Description, ' ') s
) v
where RowId <> MinRowId and Quantity is not null -- assumes one numeric per description
order by RowId;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8639811541064781083329757459054f